# Setting Grails domain id in Bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to explicitly set the id of a domain object in Grails' Bootstrap.groovy (or anywhere, for that matter)?

I've tried the following:

```
new Foo(id: 1234, name: "My Foo").save()
```

and:

```
def foo = new Foo()
foo.id = 1234
foo.name = "My Foo"
foo.save()
```

But in both cases, when I print out the results of `Foo.list()` at runtime, I see that my object has been given an id of 1, or whatever the next id in the sequence is.

**Edit:**
This is in Grails 1.0.3, and when I'm running my application in 'dev' with the built-in HSQL database.

**Edit:**
chanwit has provided [one good solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495979/setting-grails-domain-id-in-bootstrap-groovy/498145#498145). However, I was actually looking for a way to set the id without changing my domain's id generation method. This is primarily for testing: I'd like to be able to set certain things to known id values either in my test bootstrap or `setUp()`, but still be able to use auto_increment or a sequence in production.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, with manually GORM mapping:

```
class Foo {
  String name
  static mapping = {
    id generator:'assigned'
  }
}
```

and your second snippet (not the first one) will do the job (Id won't be assigned when passing it through constructor).

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up using as a workaround was to not try and retrieve objects by their id. So for the example given in the question, I changed my domain object:

```
class Foo {
  short code /* new field */
  String name

  static constraints = {
    code(unique: true)
    name()
  }
}
```

I then used an `enum` to hold all of the possible values for code (which are static), and would retrieve `Foo` objects by doing a `Foo.findByCode()` with the appropriate enum value (instead of using `Foo.get()` with the id like I wanted to do previously).

It's not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, assuming that you're importing data ***or migrating data from an existing app***, for test purposes you could use local maps within the Bootstrap file.  Think of it like an import.sql with benefits ;-)

Using this approach:

1. you wouldn't need to change your domain constraints just for
   testing,
2. you'll have a tested migration path from existing data, and
3. you'll have a good data slice (or full slice) for future integration tests

Cheers!

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    addFoos()
    addBars()

}

def foosByImportId = [:]
private addFoos(){
    def pattern = ~/.*\{FooID=(.*), FooCode=(.*), FooName=(.*)}/
    new File("import/Foos.txt").eachLine {
        def matcher = pattern.matcher(it)
        if (!matcher.matches()){
            return;
        }

        String fooId = StringUtils.trimToNull(matcher.group(1))
        String fooCode = StringUtils.trimToNull(matcher.group(2))
        String fooName = StringUtils.trimToNull(matcher.group(3))

        def foo = Foo.findByFooName(fooName) ?: new Foo(fooCode:fooCode,fooName:fooName).save(faileOnError:true)
        foosByImportId.putAt(Long.valueOf(fooId), foo) // ids could differ
    }
}

private addBars(){
    ...
    String fooId = StringUtils.trimToNull(matcher.group(5))
    def foo = foosByImportId[Long.valueOf(fooId)]
    ...
}
```